# Is there a way to limit the scope CSS float and clear?

Tags: css-float, css

Example of the problem at: http://jsfiddle.net/xZmFg/4/

Surely there is a way to get the description to immediately follow the inputs (below, not to the right) and not end up below the menu...

I realise that with 'float' you are breaking out of the flow of the content, but isn't there a way to only apply to the space inside of the parent container?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can have your description's and form inputs' parent element contain all their floats using `overflow: hidden`:

```
.content-box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This way, they won't interfere with the floats on the sidebar elements.

[jsFiddle preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/xZmFg/6)

Comment: My answer slightly differs from mu's answer in that `.content-box` stretches its width since I choose not to float it.

Comment: interesting solution - is this a documented behaviour in CSS?

Comment: after you gave me this, I was able to google a bunch about it. Looks like it is solid enough - I was just concerned that this could be one of those CSS hacks that evaporate all of a sudden.

Comment: @HorusKol: Found it - setting `overflow` to something other than `visible` gives your parent element its own [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

You can float the container around the inputs and your paragraph:

```
.content {
    float: left;
}
```

And then drop the `clear: left;` on `.description` as it doesn't do anything (or leave it in).

http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/QdY44/